# cocos2d-X call retain when calling a constructor

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

When we call a constructor on a object, do we need to call retain on the object ? I know when we call init method, it creates a auto-release object that needs to be retained ?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CCObject` (or subclasses) allocation with `new` creates object with reference counter **1**. When you call autorelease, counter remains at **1**, but autoreleased objects with counter **1** will be destroyed at the end of update cycle (app initialization or current frame).

In common cases, you create object with `create` static method, and follow common rules (`retain` only when we need to store object outside of container)

If you create object with `new` call, object created already retained once. You can call `autorelease` on it, and follow common rules, or you can store it, and manually call `release` to destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

retain is called when you:

1. add Node to another node or scene
2. add object to array
3. add object to dictionary
4. another situation that some object kept another object, which shouldn't be deleted (actions, transitions, running scene,etc.)

   When you add object to array/node/... you don't need to call retain by your own, but when you want kept object without adding to array/scene/..., you need to retain it.

Comment: how about when calling new as in new MyNode() do we have to call retain on the object.

Comment: If you want add this node to scene or node you don't need. If you need call retain after create() function. If you don't use create but only constructor you have to call autorelease before retain.